# clojure.data.json write/read affects enlive data

Tags: json, clojure, enlive

What is the appropriate  json way to save and reload `enlive`'s `html-resource` outputs.

The following procedure does not preserve the data structure (note that I ask json/read-str to map keys to symbols):

```
(require net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html)
(require clojure.data.json :as json)


(def craig-home
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. "http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites")))
(spit "./data/test_json_flow.json" (json/write-str  craig-home))

(def craig-reloaded
  (json/read-str (slurp "./data/test_json_flow.json") :key-fn keyword))

(defn count-nodes [page] (count (html/select page [:div.box :h4])))
(println (count-nodes craig-home)) ;; => 140
(println (count-nodes craig-reloaded)) ;; => 0
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

To address Mark Fischer's comment I post a  different code that address `html/select` instead of `html/html-resource`

```
(def craig-home
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. "http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites")))
(def craig-boxes (html/select craig-home [:div.box]))
(count (html/select craig-boxes [:h4])) ;; => 140

(spit "./data/test_json_flow.json" (json/write-str  craig-boxes))
(def craig-boxes-reloaded
  (json/read-str (slurp "./data/test_json_flow.json") :key-fn keyword))
(count (html/select craig-boxes-reloaded [:h4])) ;; => 0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right, your craig-reloaded and craig-home are returning different types, the reloaded version isn't returning html that the count-nodes method can use, is it?

Comment: @mark you are right. I messed up with my examples. Actually  my question was about jsonizing `html/select` results and parse them further. I update the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to write/read using Clojure [edn](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.edn-api.html):

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
(require '[clojure.data.json :as json])

(def craig-home (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. "http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites")))

(spit "./data/test_json_flow.json" (pr-str craig-home))

(def craig-reloaded
  (clojure.edn/read-string (slurp "./data/test_json_flow.json")))

(defn count-nodes [page] (count (html/select page [:div.box :h4])))
(println (count-nodes craig-home)) ;=>140
(println (count-nodes craig-reloaded)) ;=>140
```

Enlive expects the tag name value also to be a keyword and will not find a node if the tag name value is a string (which is what json/write-str and json/read-str converts keywords to).

```
(json/write-str '({:tag :h4, :attrs nil, :content ("Illinois")}))
;=> "[{\"tag\":\"h4,\",\"attrs\":null,\"content\":[\"Illinois\"]}]"

(json/read-str (json/write-str '({:tag :h4, :attrs nil, :content ("Illinois")})) :key-fn keyword)
;=> [{:tag "h4", :attrs nil, :content ["Illinois"]}]

(pr-str '({:tag :h4 :attrs nil :content ("Illinois")}))
;=> "({:tag :h4, :attrs nil, :content (\"Illinois\")})"

(clojure.edn/read-string (pr-str '({:tag :h4, :attrs nil, :content ("Illinois")})))
;=> ({:tag :h4, :attrs nil, :content ("Illinois")})
```

If you must use json then you can use the following to convert the :tag values to keywords:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk #(if-let [v (and (map? %) (:tag %))]
                          (assoc % :tag (keyword v)) %)
                       craig-reloaded)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edn suggestion. It solves my problem in the clojure word. Now suppose I want to export the results and  parse it further in python. Is there a way to produce and export in a 'universal' format?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a way to read json while converting tag values to keywords before flowing through Enlive.